# Pandas не читает csv-файл

Tags: pandas, csv, notepad++

При попытке прочитать

```
df = pd.read_csv('Данные для задания.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

csv-файл выкидывает ошибку:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 49, saw 58
```

При этом в Microsoft Excel в строках куча неразборчивых строчек такого вида:

````
РЎРѕС†РёР°Р»СЊРЅС‹Рµ СЃРµ
``` ,
но в Notepad++ при кодировке utf-8 все верно читается. Что не так?
````

Comment: скорее всего проблема с разделителями, ошибка говорит что ожидалось 6 полей в 49 строке а там судя по всему 58, не видя содержимого файла сложно судить

Comment: Ну посмотрите, что у вас в 49 строке и чем она отличается от предыдущих. Почему-то там количество полей другое, чем в более ранних строках.

Comment: вы можете выложить первые 60 строк вашего CSV файла на какой-нибудь файлообменник?